# Load gltfs from firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, firebase-storage, gltf

I have a gltf file which  exist in firebase storage folders and related textures are also located in that folders. I want to load that object into my view. I using THREE js for do this.

[image: screenshot]

I tried get download url of gltf file and pass it it GLTFLoader. But model was not loaded to view.
I tried with this :

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader()
    loader.load(
      url,
         (gltf) => {
            gltf.scene.traverse(  ( child ) => {
              if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {                  
                  console.log(child.material.metalness)
                  if(child.material.metalness){
                    child.material.envMap = texture;
                  }                      
              }            
          } );            
            var parent = gltf.scene;
            var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(parent)
            var center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3())
            var size = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3())
            var maxAxis = Math.max(size.x,size.y,size.z)            
            parent.scale.multiplyScalar(1/maxAxis)
            box.setFromObject(parent);
            box.getCenter(center)
            box.getSize(size)
            parent.position.copy(center).multiplyScalar(-1)           
            scene.add(gltf.scene)           
        },
        (xhr) => {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }
    )
```

If I load this file from local device, it is works fine and model display in view(all textures are load properly).

If anyone can help me how to load gltf file from firebase storage

Comment: Any errors in your network console?

Comment: This is console error , THREE.GLTFLoader: Couldn't load texture spaceBaseMap.png

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `getDownloadURL()` from firebase like any other file. check this out [Firebase Cloud](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#web-version-9)

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best solution but if you save the file as a .glb (binary version of .gltf), then there is only one file with textures already wrapped up in it. If not, you will need to store all the gltf data in one folder and load the whole lot including textures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We moved to glb format instead of gltf.